# If Snoke could read minds, how could this have happened?

Tags: star-wars, sith, the-last-jedi, kylo-ren, snoke

Snoke even mentions that Kylo's intentions were clear to him. Is it possible that Kylo has acquired such a power as to deceive his master?

Comment: That answer should give exactly what droids you are looking for...